# How read/write from/to same dataset, e.g. to implement caching mechanism

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have a general question: How would one read & write to the same dataset, e.g. to implement something like a caching mechanism. Naivly, this would create a cycle in the dependency graph and hence it is not allowed?

What I want to do is something like:

```
if not key in cache.keys():
  value = some_long_running_computation(key)
  cache[key] = value
return cache[key]
```

or an equivalent logic with PySpark dataframes.

I thought about incremental transforms but they do not really fit this case since they do not allow to check existence of a key in the cache and hence you would always run your code under the brittle assumption that the cache is "complete" after the incremental transform.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Tobias

Answer (score 3):

There is the ability to access the previous view of an output dataset to the transform. This is done in python when using a @dataframe decorator like so:

```
previous_output = foundry_output.dataframe("previous")
```

(you can also provide a schema.)

and in java like so:

```
foundryOutput.getExistingOutputDataFrame().get()
```

However, I would encourage this to only be used when it's absolutely essential. There's a huge benefit to keeping your pipelines fully "repeatable"/"stateless" so that you can snapshot and recompute them any time and still get the same results repeatably.

Once you introduce a "statefulness" into your pipeline, doing certain things like adding a column to your output dataset becomes much harder, since you will have to write something akin to a database migration.

That being said, it's fine to use when you really need it, and ideally keep the impact of the added complexity small.